# Ionic 5 - ion-button type="submit" css bug

Tags: css

When I add the type to the button, a rectangular shadow appears below it.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="setLoginData()">
    <ion-button class="facebook" shape="round" (click)="facebookLogin()">
        <label class="label">Entrar com o Facebook</label>
    </ion-button>
    <div class="separator"> <label style="color: #5C6B7C">ou</label> </div>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">E-mail</ion-label>
        <ion-input name="email" type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <br>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Senha</ion-label>
        <ion-input name="password" type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button class="signIn" type="submit" shape="round"> 
        <label class="label">Fazer Login</label>
    </ion-button>
</form>
```

[Image with bug in button css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoboP.png)

Without type submit works fine

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="setLoginData()">
    <ion-button class="facebook" shape="round" (click)="facebookLogin()">
        <label class="label">Entrar com o Facebook</label>
    </ion-button>
    <div class="separator"> <label style="color: #5C6B7C">ou</label> </div>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">E-mail</ion-label>
        <ion-input name="email" type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <br>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Senha</ion-label>
        <ion-input name="password" type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button class="signIn" shape="round"> 
        <label class="label">Fazer Login</label>
    </ion-button>
</form>
```

[Image without bug in button css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TTP6.png)

Answer (score 1):

added this in my global stylesheet with the previous answer's css so that it is for every submit type button in the app:

```
ion-button[type=submit] {
  appearance:         none;
  -moz-appearance:    none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug.. but I can assume it has something todo with appearance.
Try add this:

```css
.signIn,
.signIn button {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
}
```

Comment: This corrected the problem.

Thank you for your help!